# c# cast a value obtained from FieldInfo

Tags: c#-4.0

Grade in an Enum Structure.

```
  var y=1;
  var x= (Grade)y;
```

I'm trying to do the same thing as the above line but with a dynamic CLASSNAME.

```
    FieldInfo field = typeof(Person).GetField("Grade");
    var x= Convert.ChangeType(y ,field.FieldType);
```

I tried that. this works fine but not for enums.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the way you are accessing the field on the enum.  Enum fields are static.  By default, the `Type.GetField` method uses binding flags equivalent to `BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance`.  This won't match an enum member.

If this is the problem you are having, then you can use `typeof(Person).GetField("Grade",BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static)` to get the `FieldInfo` for the field named "Grade" on the enum type named "Person".  This assumes that your model looks like:

```
 enum Person
 {
    Grade
 }
```

There's another problem with your code that is compatible with enums as well.  It's not totally obvious because your example seems to treat "Grade" as both a field and an type.  If my previous suggestion doesn't describe your model, and the following does, then the problem is that you are using `Convert.ChangeType` which  in this case should give you an `InvalidCastException`.

You need to find a different way to cast the value to your enum.  If the class name is not known at compile-time, then I would suggest using linq expressions, e.g.

```
Type targetEnumType = typeof(Person).GetField("Grade");
ConstantExpression runtimeValue = Expression.Constant(y);
UnaryExpression cast = Expression.Convert(runtimeValue,targetEnumType);
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(cast);
Delegate getTheCastValue = lambda.Compile();
object value = getTheCastValue.DynamicInvoke();
```

This code assumes that your model looks something like

```
 class Person 
 { 
     public Grade Grade;
 }

 enum Grade
 {
     First = 1,
     Second = 2
 }
```

However, looking at this, it becomes obvious that if `Person` is a non-generic class, then you would have to know the type of the `Grade` field at runtime, so you are better off just doing a `(Grade)y` cast, like in your example.

Comment: thanks, it accesses the field successfully. but i get Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'Project1.Grade'.

Comment: Thanks 
my model has fields not properties(get;set;)

Comment: @nullException, are you still having issues with this?